# Private enum location inside a class in Java

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

When declaring an enum inside a class in java I've seen these 2 approaches:

1)

```
public class MyClass {

    private enum MyEnum {
        A, B, C;
    }

    /* Static fields */

    /* Instance variables */

    /* Methods */
}
```

2)

```
public class MyClass {

    /* Static fields */

    /* Instance variables */

    /* Methods */

    private enum MyEnum {
        A, B, C;
    }
}
```

Which one is the most used? Is there any convention for this?

Comment: Is there any problem if you place it differently?

Comment: @Rupesh I just want to know if there is a convention for this or if it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: no not at all and to be on safer side `not that I know of`. Refer my answer below

Comment: I would prefer the first one

Comment: I prefer to declare `enum` etc before I use them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Generally in Java, nested data types (e.g. classes, enums) go at the bottom of a file.

However, for short, private enums like the one you posted (which feel more like fields), I'd go with #1.

For longer enums, I'd either go with #2 or put them in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any convention used for it, but from what I've seen, example 1 is used more often. I personally place them in that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a `typedef` statement (as in C and C++). To declare new types in Java, you declare a new class; then variables can be declared to be of that class's type. Also Java uses **Forward references**, java compiler is smarter than the C compiler, in that it allows methods to be invoked before they are defined. This eliminates the need to declare functions in a header file before defining them in a program file, as is done in C.

I can place my `enum` anywhere and can access it from anywhere. Refer example.

```
class CheckEnum{

    private void method1() {
        System.out.println(enumTest.test1);    
    }       
    private enum enumTest{
        test1
    }       
    private void method2() {
        System.out.println(enumTest.test1);
    }
}
```

I have checked and both method `method1` and `method2` has access to `enumTest`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with either of them. It's more a matter of opinion but I would go go #1.